# Embed Google / Microsoft Excel spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, excel-online

I'm searching for few hours for a web app which allows me to create a spreadsheet and embed in to my webpage.

I've looked through Microsoft Excel web app and Google spreadsheets, but none of them allow me to edit the embedded file directly from my webpage.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Give these a look, they use JavaScript:<br> http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxSpreadsheet/index.shtml Or https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid

Answer (score 5):

Google will allow you to directly edit a spreadsheet in an `iframe`. I've got this on some of my sites.

In my case, the sharing in the spreadsheet is set to "Anyone with the link" "Can edit". Not sure how it would work if you require authentication.